# how can i calculate the distances between 5 points using the dist() function?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

`dist()` calculates the distance between two points, however i want to calculate the distance between 5 points (distance between the point in a circle, and the four points in a rectangle (each corner has a point) ) how can i do this?

```js
intersects(other){

    let di =  dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y)
    let di2 =  dist(this.x, this.y, other.x + 80, other.y)
    let di3 =  dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y + 150)
    let di4 =  dist(this.x, this.y, other.x + 80, other.y + 150)
    if (di && di2 && di3 && di4 <= this.r) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

i tried to hardcode it, but the if function only uses "di4"

Comment: i think what you want to do is ```if (di <= this.r && di2 <= this.r && di3 <= this.r && di4 <= this.r)```

Comment: do you know the exact dimensions (height or width) of the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, i know the exact dimensins

Comment: I'm not sure you actually need to do things the way you're describing: what are you _actually_ trying to do? Are you trying to determine whether `this` lies inside a specific (axis-aligned) bounding box?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i figured it out. I had to make a distance function for each of the corners in the rectangle

Comment: So you were trying to determine whether a point was inside a rectangle?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes

Comment: Then you _really_ need to edit your post title and text, because you don't want "the distance between 5 points" then.

Comment: Well, that is what i did and it sort of worked, but if you have any other ideas then feel free to share @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I meant update the title to reflect "determining whether a point is inside a rectangle" and updating the post to reflect that you want four distances, not "one distance between 5 points".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to verify if **all the distances are below** a certain threshold, then you've to compare all the values to the reference distance and to concatenate the results by **`&&`**:

```js
if (di <= this.r && di2 <= this.r && di3 <= this.r && di4 <= this.r) {
    // [...]
}
```

If you want to verify if **any of the distances is below** a certain threshold, then you've to compare all the values to the reference distance and to concatenate the results by **`||`**:

```js
if (di <= this.r || di2 <= this.r || di3 <= this.r || di4 <= this.r) {
    // [...]
}
```

If you want to get the maximum of a list of values, then you can use the [`max()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/max) function. This is equal to the evaluation if all the distances are below `this.r`:

```js
if (max([di, di2, di3, di4]) <= this.r) {
   // [...]
}
```

If you want to get the minimum of a list of values, then you can use the [`min()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/min) function. This is equal to the evaluation if any of the distances is below `this.r`:

```js
if (min([di, di2, di3, di4]) <= this.r) {
   // [...]
}
```

Note, the expression

> ```js
> di && di2 && di3 && di4 <= this.r
> ```

doesn't do what you expect it to do. Only `d14` is compared to `this.r`. The other terms evaluate to `true` if they are not undefined an the values are not equal 0.0.
This means the expression can be read as `di != 0 && di2 != 0 && di3 != 0 && di4 <= this.r`

---

But note, if you want to verify if a circle is completely inside a rectangle, then you've to verify if the distance of the circle to each side (rather than corner point) is above (rather than below) the radius of the circle:

```js
intersects(other){

    let di  =  this.x - other.x;       // distance to the left 
    let di2 =  other.x + 80 - this.x;  // distance to the right
    let di3 =  this.y - other.y;       // distance to the top
    let di4 =  other.y + 150 - this.y; // distance to the bottom
    if (di >= this.r && di2 >= this.r && di3 >= this.r && di4 >= this.r) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to verify the distance to the center of the rectangle, too, then you've to calculate the distance to the center by [`dist()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist).
So if you want to verify if the circle hits the center  point or any side of the rectangle, then you've o check if any of the distances is below the radius

```js
let di  =  this.x - other.x;       // distance to the left 
let di2 =  other.x + 80 - this.x;  // distance to the right
let di3 =  this.y - other.y;       // distance to the top
let di4 =  other.y + 150 - this.y; // distance to the bottom

// distance to the center point
let di5 = dist(this.x, this.y, other.x + 80/2, other.y + 150/2);

if (di <= this.r || di2 <= this.r || di3 <= this.r && di4 <= this.r && di5 <= this.r) {
    // [...]
}
```

or

```js
if (min([di, di2, di3, di4, di5]) <= this.r) {
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: I wanted to verify if all the distances are below a certain threshold, like you showed i the first example, however it still doesnt work

Comment: @Mr.Ulis Why do you mat to do that? If all the distances are below, then this would mean that all the 4 points are in the circle, which seems to be impossible. if you want to verify if a circle is completely inside a rectangle, the see the last section of the answer.

Comment: Ahhh, the last section is what i wanted, thank you!

Comment: However the last section only makes the circle react to the top and bottom part of the rectangle, does this mean that i have to make a new point (di5) for the middle part?

Comment: So you want that the point reacts on the center of the rectangle, too, then the the new last section of the answer? Or do you mean the center line from the left to the right?

Comment: @Mr.Ulis Yes this is what the last section of the answer does. You've to verify if the distance is above the radius. If you want to verify the distance to a point then you've to use `dist()`. If you want to verify the distance a horizontal or vertical edge then it is sufficient to subtract either the x or y coordinates.

Comment: One last question. Is this "if (min([di, di2, di3, di4]) <= this.r)" statement essentially saying that if the radius of the circle is bigger or equal to the smallest distance between the cirle and the rectangle, then it is true?

Comment: @Mr.Ulis Yes it is. I've changed the last section of the answer.